# Replace XML element with Java

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

In the below XML, I would like to change the value of the <Password> element using Java.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:Envelope xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <ns1:Header>
        <ns2:Security>
            <ns2:UsernameToken xmlns:ns3="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <ns2:Username>ADMIN</ns2:Username>
            <ns2:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">abcd</ns2:Password>
            <ns3:Created>2016-09-08T17:47:05.079Z</ns3:Created>
            </ns2:UsernameToken>
        </ns2:Security>
    </ns1:Header>
    <ns1:Body>
    </ns1:Body>
</ns1:Envelope>
```

I tried with the following code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(new File("D:/test.xml"));  
Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
root.getElementsByTagName("Password").item(0).setTextContent("efgh");
```

But I am getting NullPointerException. This is because getElementsByTagName is returning a NodeList with 0 elements. I tried using getElementsByTagNameNS instead, but the result is still the same.

```
root.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", "Password").item(0).setTextContent("efgh");
```

What else can I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you tried `root.getElementsByTagName("ns2:Password")` instead?

Comment: This will work, but the problem is that the prefix is not necessarily "ns2". The XML is generated by JAXB and it can assign whatever prefix it wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your `DocumentBuilderFactory` to be namespace aware:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(new File("D:/test.xml"));
    Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
    root.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", "Password").item(0).setTextContent("efgh");

    // Write out result to check it
    TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
    transformer.transform(source, result);
}
```